# is there a library to convert transaction receipt to rlp?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, rlp

I found ethereumjs-tx for transaction to rlp, but i didnt find any libraries to convert transaction reciept to rlp. or is there a way to get rlp format transaction receipt from a service like infura or parity with a given transaction hash?